# mysql - can't get query to work

Tags: mysql

I can't for the life of me see what is going wrong here. Its most likely something stupid, but I'm blind to it currently! I have a query:

```
SELECT 
Links.Title,
(6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.4347229) ) * cos( radians( Links.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Links.Longitude ) - radians(6.737222195) ) + sin( radians(43.4347229) ) * sin( radians( Links.Latitude ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM CatLinks,Links WHERE CatLinks.LinkID = Links.ID AND (Links.ID IN (16650,17190,153344) AND Links.isValidated = 'Yes' AND Links.PropertyType IN (1,2,3) AND Links.priceSort <= '9999' AND Links.PropertyType IN (1,2,3) AND Links.priceSort < '9999') ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0,50
```

..to which I get an error:

> Error: Could not execute query: Failed to execute query: 'SELECT
>   Links.Title, (6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.4347229) ) * cos( radians(
>   Links.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Links.Longitude ) -
>   radians(6.737222195) ) + sin( radians(43.4347229) ) * sin( radians(
>   Links.Latitude ) ) ) AS distance FROM CatLinks,Links WHERE
>   CatLinks.LinkID = Links.ID AND (Links.ID IN (16650,17190,153344))
>   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0,50': You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AS distance FROM CatLinks,Links WHERE
>   CatLinks.LinkID =' at line 3

Even trimming it down to a much simpler query, doesn't want to work:

```
SELECT 
    glinks_Links.Title,
    (6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.4347229) ) * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( glinks_Links.Longitude ) - radians(6.737222195) ) + sin( radians(43.4347229) ) * sin( radians( glinks_Links.Latitude ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Links ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0,50
```

I've been going round and round with this issue all morning, so any advice would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close a bracket (near `sin( radians( Links.Latitude ) ) ) )`). Try this

```
SELECT
    Links.Title,
    (
        6371 * acos(
            cos(radians(43.4347229)) * cos(radians(Links.Latitude)) * cos(
                radians(Links.Longitude) - radians(6.737222195)
            ) + sin(radians(43.4347229)) * sin(radians(Links.Latitude))
        )
    ) AS distance
FROM
    CatLinks,
    Links
WHERE
    CatLinks.LinkID = Links.ID
AND (
    Links.ID IN (16650, 17190, 153344)
    AND Links.isValidated = 'Yes'
    AND Links.PropertyType IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND Links.priceSort <= '9999'
    AND Links.PropertyType IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND Links.priceSort < '9999'
)
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT 0,50
```

Comment: Yes - basically add a close bracket before the "AS"

Comment: Ah man - can't believe i missed that! I've been staring at the query for a good hour now! Thanks for the time save - I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as it'll allow :)